# Como setar margem em uma TextView no código fonte do java?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

Quando estou no `xml`, apenas aplica a propriedade:

`android:margin="15"`

Quero fazer a aplicação desta mesma propriedade, só que, no código fonte do `java`, como faço isso?

Answer (score 2):

Basta setar a margem no `LayoutParams` da `View` e pedir uma nova avaliação do `Layout`:

```
View view = ...

ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();

if(lp instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) lp;

    lp.margin = 15;

    // Nao esqueca de requisitar o reajuste no layout
    view.requestLayout();

}
```

Comment: como eu faço para adicionar a margem em uma TextView? @Wakim

Comment: Everton, esse código funciona para qualquer View. Se a margem não aplicou visualmente, pode ser algum problema com a largura e/ou altura do TextView. Seria legal colocar a declaração do mesmo.